# Shell Command in PHP file : Display the content of a file in a webpage

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu

I need some help, how can I execute a shell command in a php file? on how to display the content of a file in a webpage.

I tested this script, it works

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls /var/www/vhosts/resame');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

but this script, did not display anything.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cat /var/log/mail.log');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages (check your web server log also)? try `shell_exec('cat /var/log/mail.log 2>&1')`. most probably web server don't have permission to read `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: Modify your shell command to 'cat /var/log/mail.log 2>&1' to get the errors into your web output as well.

Comment: thank you for the responds :) it says permission denied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command first (based on your apache user)

`CHMOD 777 /var/log/mail.log`

If apache user is nobody
`CHOWN nobody /var/log/mail.log`

If apache user is www-data
`CHOWN www-data /var/log/mail.log`

Then use the following to display data on the web page.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('cat /var/log/mail.log 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good one @DJ, let me also add that permission 777 for /var/log/mail.log is not necessary since you are only reading the file content, permission 644 should be enough. I do not need to over-flog the security implication changing your public file permission to 777.